# difference between "crawling like arrangement" and "stabilized arrangement"

Tags: exchange-rates, foreign-exchange, currency-exchange, pure-exchange-economy, exchange

What is the difference between "crawling like arrangement" and "stabilized arrangement" ?
what about margins ? both less than + or -1% ?